# How to input SUM formula with variable number of cells select in for loop

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm developing a vba that projects the cost of a service. It calculates the quantitie of quotas and it's respective value (Colunms N and O). After the vba runs, the quantitie can be edited by the user and the value is recalculated. Now I have to input a SUM formula in a cell (Colunm M) that will sum the total of quantities of the quotas in the same row, however it is done in a for loop and for each supplier the number of quotas is variable (Number of quotas = qtdMeses), as seen in the code below. I'm having trouble to construct the SUM formula for each row. How can I put it in the code?

[image]

[image]

```
Sub ProcessarProjecaoEst()

Dim fLine, qtdMeses, LastLine, lineTitle, LastCol, LastColTitle, valor_col, valor_parc, novalinhaleilao, fim, ult_col
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Leilao")
Set wparam = wb.Sheets("Parametros")

ws.Activate

qtdMeses = ws.Range("B4")
lineTitle = 11
PrimeiraColunaQtde = 14


' Ativa a aba PARAMETROS
wparam.Activate
qtdeLinhasParam = wparam.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

' Ativa a aba LEILAO
ws.Activate
qtdeLinhasLeilao = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

''PERCORRER PELOS PARAMETROS DOS LOTES
For lineParam = 6 To qtdeLinhasParam
    qtdMeses = wparam.Range("C" & lineParam)
    For lineLeilao = 12 To qtdeLinhasLeilao
        If (ws.Range("A" & lineLeilao).Value = "0") And ws.Range("B" & lineLeilao).Value = "Lote " + wparam.Range("A" & lineParam) Then
            'Gerar Cabecalhos
            For i = 1 To qtdMeses
                
                    'Se for primeira PARCELA
                    If (i = 1) Then
                            LastColTitle = ws.Cells(lineLeilao, 16384).End(xlToLeft).Column
                            LastColTitle = PrimeiraColunaQtde
                            valueMes = wparam.Range("B" & lineParam).Value
                            ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 3, LastColTitle), Cells(lineLeilao - 3, LastColTitle)).NumberFormat = "mmm-yy"
                            ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 3, LastColTitle), Cells(lineLeilao - 3, LastColTitle)) = valueMes
                            ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 3, LastColTitle), Cells(lineLeilao - 3, LastColTitle)).HorizontalAlignment = xlVAlignCenter
                            ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 3, LastColTitle), Cells(lineLeilao - 3, LastColTitle)).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 242, 204)
                            ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 3, LastColTitle), Cells(lineLeilao - 3, LastColTitle)).Font.Color = Black
                            
                            ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 3, LastColTitle), Cells(lineLeilao - 3, LastColTitle)).WrapText = True
                            ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 3, LastColTitle), Cells(lineLeilao - 3, LastColTitle)).Font.Size = 9
                            ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 3, LastColTitle), Cells(lineLeilao - 3, LastColTitle)).Font.Bold = True
                            
                            ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle), Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle)) = "Parcela" & i
                            ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle), Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle)).HorizontalAlignment = xlVAlignCenter
                            ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle), Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle)).Interior.Color = RGB(21, 48, 65)
                            ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle), Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle)).Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
                            ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle), Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle)).WrapText = True
                            ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle), Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle)).Font.Size = 9
                            ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle), Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle)).Font.Bold = True
                            
                                                
                            LastColTitle = ws.Cells(lineLeilao - 2, 16384).End(xlToLeft).Column
                            ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle + 1)) = "Parcela" & i
                            ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle + 1)).HorizontalAlignment = xlVAlignCenter
                            ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle + 1)).Interior.Color = RGB(21, 48, 65)
                            ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle + 1)).Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
                            ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle + 1)).WrapText = True
                            ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle + 1)).Font.Size = 9
                            ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle + 1)).Font.Bold = True
                            
                            '11
                            LastCol = ws.Cells(lineLeilao - 1, 16384).End(xlToLeft).Column
                            LastCol = PrimeiraColunaQtde
                            ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol), Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol)) = "Qtde"
                            ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol), Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol)).HorizontalAlignment = xlVAlignCenter
                            ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol), Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol)).VerticalAlignment = xlVAlignCenter
                            ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol), Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol)).WrapText = True
                            ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol), Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol)).Font.Size = 9
                            ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol), Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol)).Font.Bold = True
                            
                            LastCol = ws.Cells(lineLeilao - 1, 16384).End(xlToLeft).Column
                            ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol + 1)) = "Valor"
                            ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol + 1)).HorizontalAlignment = xlVAlignCenter
                            ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol + 1)).VerticalAlignment = xlVAlignCenter
                            ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol + 1)).WrapText = True
                            ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol + 1)).Font.Size = 9
                            ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol + 1)).Font.Bold = True
                        
                    Else
                           LastColTitle = ws.Cells(lineLeilao - 2, 16384).End(xlToLeft).Column
                           valueMes = wparam.Range("B" & lineParam).Value
                           ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 3, LastColTitle + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 3, LastColTitle + 1)).NumberFormat = "mmm-yy"
                           ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 3, LastColTitle + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 3, LastColTitle + 1)).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(RC[-2]+31)"
                           ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 3, LastColTitle + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 3, LastColTitle + 1)).HorizontalAlignment = xlVAlignCenter
                           ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 3, LastColTitle + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 3, LastColTitle + 1)).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 242, 204)
                           ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 3, LastColTitle + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 3, LastColTitle + 1)).Font.Color = Black
                           ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 3, LastColTitle + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 3, LastColTitle + 1)).WrapText = True
                           ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 3, LastColTitle + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 3, LastColTitle + 1)).Font.Size = 9
                           ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 3, LastColTitle + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 3, LastColTitle + 1)).Font.Bold = True
                           
                                      
                           ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle + 1)) = "Parcela" & i
                           ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle + 1)).HorizontalAlignment = xlVAlignCenter
                           ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle + 1)).Interior.Color = RGB(21, 48, 65)
                           ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle + 1)).Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
                           ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle + 1)).WrapText = True
                           ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle + 1)).Font.Size = 9
                           ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle + 1)).Font.Bold = True
                                              
                                                     
                           LastColTitle = ws.Cells(lineLeilao - 2, 16384).End(xlToLeft).Column
                           ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle + 1)) = "Parcela" & i
                           ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle + 1)).HorizontalAlignment = xlVAlignCenter
                           ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle + 1)).Interior.Color = RGB(21, 48, 65)
                           ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle + 1)).Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
                           ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle + 1)).WrapText = True
                           ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle + 1)).Font.Size = 9
                           ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle + 1)).Font.Bold = True
                    
                           '11
                           LastCol = ws.Cells(lineLeilao - 1, 16384).End(xlToLeft).Column
                           ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol + 1)) = "Qtde"
                           ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol + 1)).HorizontalAlignment = xlVAlignCenter
                           ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol + 1)).VerticalAlignment = xlVAlignCenter
                           ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol + 1)).WrapText = True
                           ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol + 1)).Font.Size = 9
                           ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol + 1)).Font.Bold = True
                           ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol + 1)).Font.Color = Black
                           
                           LastCol = ws.Cells(lineLeilao - 1, 16384).End(xlToLeft).Column
                           ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol + 1)) = "Valor"
                           ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol + 1)).HorizontalAlignment = xlVAlignCenter
                           ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol + 1)).VerticalAlignment = xlVAlignCenter
                           ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol + 1)).WrapText = True
                           ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol + 1)).Font.Size = 9
                           ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol + 1)).Font.Bold = True
                           ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol + 1)).Font.Color = Black
             
             End If

            Next
    If ws.Range("A" & lineLeilao) = 0 Then
        novalinhaleilao = lineLeilao + 1
    End If
    'LastCol = ws.Cells(11, 16384).End(xlToLeft).Column
    If lineParam = 6 Then
       LastCol = ws.Cells(11, 16384).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Else
       
       LastCol = ws.Cells(ult_col, 16384).End(xlToLeft).Column
       lineTitle = novalinhaleilao - 2
    End If
    'Inserindo Fórmulas
    LastLine = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For Row = 11 To LastLine
    If fim <> 0 And ws.Range("A" & lineLeilao) = 0 Then
            Row = novalinhaleilao
            
            fim = 0
    End If
        For col = PrimeiraColunaQtde To LastCol
            If ws.Range("A" & Row).Value = "F1" Then
                 If ws.Range(Cells(lineTitle, col), Cells(lineTitle, col)).Value = "Qtde" Then
                     ' Qtde Dividida
                      ws.Range(Cells(Row, col), Cells(Row, col)).NumberFormat = "0"
                      ws.Range(Cells(Row, col), Cells(Row, col)) = ws.Range(Cells(Row, 4), Cells(Row, 4)).Value / qtdMeses
                 Else
                    ' Valor dividido
                       ws.Range(Cells(Row, col), Cells(Row, col)).NumberFormat = _
                        "_-[$R$-pt-BR] * #,##0.00_-;-[$R$-pt-BR] * #,##0.00_-;_-[$R$-pt-BR] * ""-""??_-;_-@_-"
                     ws.Range(Cells(Row, col), Cells(Row, col)).FormulaR1C1 = "= RC[-1]/" & qtdMeses
                     ws.Range(Cells(Row, col), Cells(Row, col)).ColumnWidth = 15
                 End If
            End If
            If IsEmpty(ws.Range("A" & Row)) = True Then
                
                GoTo prox
            End If
        Next
    Next

     End If
    Next
prox:   fim = 1
        novalinhaleilao = Row + 1
        ult_col = novalinhaleilao
    Next


End Sub
```

Comment: I am having difficulty understanding some of the logic in the code, it might help if you could post a screenshot of the first few columns of the Parametros sheet.

Comment: @CDP1802 Edited the post and posted the screenshot of the sheet 'Parametros'

Comment: @FaneDuru here is a question that you might be able to help me too

Comment: Thanks for the added screenshot. One part I can't understand is after 'Inserindo Fórmulas` the line `If ws.Range("A" & Row).Value = "F1" Then` as I can't see F1 anywhere in column A. Also which rows need the total added, it is the line below the Parcelas ?

Comment: Hi @CDP1802! it is not possible to add a screenshot right now but the "F1" is filling the cells in the colunm A, where there is a supplier product, for example "Cabo 10" or "Embalagem". The row that needs to be summed are the rows where there is this "F1" in colunm A and in the colunm is written "Qtde", howerver in wich supplier, there is a different extension of colunms, for example, for the first two suppliers, there will be 3 colunms in the sum, in the next one, there will be 4 colunms. The extension of the sum is set on the sheet parametros.

Comment: Which is LIne11 ? Are any rows hidden on the screenshot between Lancamentos and Lote 4 ?

Comment: Line 11 is the row where is placed Lançamentos and ther is no hidden rows

Answer (score 0):

Create a function to build a formula string.

```vb
   'Add formula to col M using count of parcelas*/2
    Dim n As Long
    With ws
        For lineLeilao = 10 To qtdeLinhasLeilao
           If .Cells(lineLeilao, "N") Like "Parcela*" Then
                n = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Rows(lineLeilao), "Parcela*")
           ElseIf .Cells(lineLeilao, "A") = "F1" Then
                .Cells(lineLeilao, "M").FormulaR1C1 = QuotaSum(n / 2)
           End If
        Next
    End With

Function QuotaSum(n) As String
    Dim f As String, i As Long
    For i = 1 To n * 2 Step 2
       f = f & "+RC[" & i & "]"
    Next
    QuotaSum = "=" & f
End Function
```

Comment: @Matheus I have updated answer with  code that you can add before the End Sub

Comment: Thanks @CDP1802, I will study it here and try to implement. Any further questions I'll come back here. Thanks for your attention